# how to request page to server by scrolling the screen

Tags: android

I'm trying to get some picture URL from server. 
To avoid data loss, the server send me just 1 page, and each page has 5 URL.

So, if I scroll all the way to the bottom, my app requests another page. 
how can I implements this function?

(Please think about Facebook app. when you scroll all the way to the bottom, more picture comes out)

Comment: do you mean paginate recyclerview? this library is easy to use [Paginate](https://github.com/MarkoMilos/Paginate)..

Comment: Try to provide sample code...